# 3.3V TTL to other formats and impedance matching

Tags: transmission-line, rs232, ttl, max232

I am trying to convert a 3.3V 50 Ohm Impedance TTL Pulse-per-second into other formats (GPIB, USB, RS-232, etc.). I've found some format adapters/convertors like the MAX232, but I am either misunderstanding something or missing something.

So I know the TTL line has a 50 Ohm impedance, and from looking at the RS-232 standards, the impedance is 3k-7k (?). I imagine the MAX 232 doesn't convert/impedance match. So, do I have to do my own impedance matching from 50 --> MAX 232 --> Whatever the RS-232 is (any idea how I can find out from the spec since if it is indeed 3k-7k, thats pretty much pure reflection if im not mistaken).

Comment: Reflections don't appear inside ICs, they appear in transmission lines. You should describe those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a long transmission line at the 3.3V signal, you only have to worry about terminating that properly, however if the output has 50 ohm source termination, whatever reflection happens at the end will get terminated at the source, so it may not be a problem. Then, the RS232 driver outputs have slew rate limiting at the driver output and it requires no termination, as serial port lines do not use impedance matching, they use voltage as the signal so output impedance is low and input impedance is high.

Comment: What defines long? Does 1m/~3ft count for long? 
I'm confused regarding the 50 ohm source termination. From this datasheet https://www.serialcomm.com/USB_adapters/USB_converters/usb_to_3v_ttl_adapter/usb_to_3v_ttl_adapter.product_general_info.aspx
there seems to be no mention of source termination. Most converters for anything dont seem to list anything about termination or impedance. I'm sure im missing something?
Also, doesn't having a slew rate essentially destroy the whole purpose of the PPS since slew delays/ruins the integrity of the signal?

Comment: Long is actually a relative term regarding to bandwidth of the signal, or slew rate. If rise time is slow enough in comparison to the length and speed it travels along the wire, it is not considered a transmission line so transmission line effects like termination become unimportant. Perhaps RS232 is not a right physical interface for your signal if it does not allow for skew or delay.

Comment: Is there a formula for this to figure out if its considered a transmission line? 
If my line is 6 ft long and rise time is typically 1.5 ns (so 1.5E-9 < ~2m/3E8 == 1.5E-9 < 6.667E-9). 
My options of interface are USB2.0, USB3.0, GPIB, RS-232, and ethernet. From my research it seems like USB, Ethernet, and GPIB have a large latency so seems like 232 is the best option? (also to convert 3.3TTL to USB, it seems like I need to convert to Rs-232 anyway?)

Comment: Common rule of thumb is that if the the cable length is greater than 1/10 of the wavelength, it can be considered as a transmission line. Typically RS232 is used at below 200kbps, so it has a max slew rate of 30V/us, and tranceivers can easily have propagation delay of 500ns. Also USB RS232 serial ports can be quite limited, as they are typically devices that use 1ms polling rate at the USB interface. And USB TTL serial ports exist, they just don't have a separate TTL to RS232 tranceiver, so no, there is no need to convert to RS232 anyway.

Comment: Oh wow, this is a lot to process and to digest. Thank you! Do you have any advice, recommendations, or suggestions on the best route to ingest a 1 PPS with the least amount of latency?
My PPS is from an NTP server so I also have to convert from a BNC female port to something suitable too (surprisingly annoying finding BNC to ... converters/adapters).

Comment: So I found a USB to TTL converter cable (TTL-232RG-VSW3V3-WE), but how do I impedance match it? I know the source has a 50 ohm impedance, but I have no idea about the cable/converter. I believe USB has 90 ohms of impedance?

Comment: USB impedance relates to USB wiring, and you are not connecting to USB wiring. Your output has 50 ohm impedance, but really the TTL 3.3V data input on the FTDI chip is not terminated nor it does not need impedance matching. All you need to take care is that since it is a device with 3.3V IO levels, your TTL signal does not exceed that. If it is a 5V signal then you might consider the version with 5V IO levels.

Comment: So just to go full circle,
My PPS has a 50 Ohm impedance (from a syncserver S650), and I plan on connecting it to a BNC to single ended split ends (since the PPS has an BNC output). From the split ends, if I connect it to the FTDI chip and then to the USB/Computer, I should be good to go? Shouldnt there be reflection eventually since I imagine the USB/Computer has an impedance?

Also, just want to say thank you for all your help. Your selflessness has been greatly appreciated

Comment: Why didn't you say what the device is in the first place? The manual clearly says it's "TTL into 50 ohms". Therefore, you put 50 ohms termination at the FTDI chip input. The transmission line you need to care about ends there. The USB between the chip and computer is already been taken care of and it's nothing you need to worry about.

Comment: I thought the "TTL into 50 ohms" was just for IRIG? I guess I got confused from reading this (http://pos.mgb-tech.com/insightpps/) prior to posting this question. Since the manual says its a 50 ohm impedance, I thought it was a 50 ohm signal interface (in hindsight, maybe thats redundant to being TTL into 50 ohms)? 

so then is it a bad idea to have it go from NTP to flying leads since those dont have a specified impedance and could throw everything off? (https://www.newark.com/pomona/4970/bnc-male-plug-to-flying-leads/dp/94F1507?MER=sy-me-pd-mi-alte#anchorTechnicalDOCS)

Comment: Yes, it is a bad idea to use that adapter if it is a super fast pulse meant to be sent without much distortion from a 50 ohm BNC output over a 50 ohm coax cable into a 50 ohm load.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112537/discussion-between-bchang32-and-justme).